# Installing a file to the GAC through a Sharepoint 2007 WSP package

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I'm creating a WSP package in Visual Studio 2010 to deploy my feature to the sharepoint 2007 environment on a Windows 2003 Server box.  Currently, the xml file that references the assembly containing the code I have written is referenced from the GAC.  What I'd like to do is make it so this WSP file will add the dll to the assembly automatically and then reference it so the feature can be properly installed.  Is this possible? If so, how is this done?

I have my ListManifest.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
    <Receiver>
        <Name>AddedEventHandler</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Assembly>
            SPEventHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
            PublicKeyToken=f2e7de6c4a924a03
        </Assembly>
        <Class>SPEventHandler.ItemAddedHandler</Class>
        <Data></Data>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </Receiver>
</Receivers>
```

As you can see, it references the SPEventHandler assembly in the GAC, but I'd like the program to have my DLL included in the assembly, add it to the GAC and reference it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

If you are packaging your wsp manually, then you need to include your dll in your DDF file, 
bin\Debug\MyFile.dll MyFile.dll
and you include the assembly in the solution manifest, e.g.

```
<Assemblies>
  <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="MyFile.dll" />
</Assemblies>
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466225%28office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which version of sharepoint but here is an article on how include extra assemblies in your package for sharepoint 2010

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/

Comment: doh sorry. here's an article for 2007
 http://sharepointlogics.com/2008/11/how-to-deploy-assembly-using-wsp.html